# Why does this display string index out of range?

Tags: python

```
s = 'vazaedfsakl'
ccc = lll = s[0]
print(ccc[-1])
print(ccc[0])
print(ccc[1])
print(lll[-1])
print(lll[0])
print(lll[1])
```

while ccc[-1] and ccc[0] prints out v, ccc[1] shows string index out of range. Same goes for lll variable too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ccc` has one element, `ccc[0]`. `ccc[1]` does not exist.

Comment: but ccc[0] and lll[0] prints out fine. If one element then why does it have to start from -1 position?

Comment: ccc does not start from -1. Python treats a negatve index as counting from just past the end of the list and counting backward, so an index of [-1] gives the last element in the list. Try printing s[-1].

Comment: I see. I never knew this! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`s[0]` is the letter `v`. This is what you assign to `ccc` and `lll`. It only has 1 value, therefore the first index from the beginning (`[0]`) and the first index from the end (`[-1]`) are the only valid indices.

To see this in action, here we label the character with the index going forward:

```
for i in range(11):
    print(i, s[i])
0 v
1 a
2 z
3 a
4 e
5 d
6 f
7 s
8 a
9 k
10 l
```

and here we go backward:

```
for i in range(-11,0):
    print(i, s[i])
-11 v
-10 a
-9 z
-8 a
-7 e
-6 d
-5 f
-4 s
-3 a
-2 k
-1 l
```

Comment: Then when assigned one string ("v" for example) then the max range of the variable is from [-1, 1]? And if two strings then [-2,2]?

Comment: Basicall, yes, as long as the end is non-inclusive, see [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm). Python lists/strings/iterables are _zero-indexed_, which means the first character or item is at index `0`. A 2-character string has indices `0` and `1`. If you count backward (as in when you pass it a negative number) the valid indices are `-1` and `-2`